# Angular material select not opening options

Tags: angular, angular-material

My mat select option do not show for some reason. The label or the option do not show.

Here is my code

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Tags</mat-label>
  <input matInput placeholder="Tags" value="" class="mat-input-custom">
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Subjects</mat-label>
  <input matInput placeholder="Subjects" value="" class="mat-input-custom">
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field class="full-width">
  <mat-label>Resolution</mat-label>
  <mat-select formControlName="resolution">
    <mat-option>HD</mat-option>
    <mat-option>4K</mat-option>
    <mat-option>Amateur</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

I created a stackblitz showing the code here
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-select-demo-oksugs

Comment: Add value tag to each option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into your console to see errors. The error is happening due to your `input`, which in turn is causing issues with the `mat-select`. You need to import the `MatInputModule` module.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-select-demo-vbyl4v) is your updated StackBlitz.